# How to run simple php code with jquery/ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Because my actual example is way too big I made a very short example:

**test1.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script> <!--jQuery-->
<body>
<p> What is the first letter of the alphabet?</p>
<button type="button" id="button">Tell me!</button>
<div id="div"></div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#button').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'test2.php',
            success: function() {
                $('#div').html();
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**test2.php**

```
<?php
echo "It's the letter A!";
?>
```

I want to this to print out "It's the letter A!" when I hit the button, which does not seem to work. Could somebody help end tell me why this doesn't work and how to fix it?
Thanks

Comment: should be enclosed by quotes `$('#button')` ,

Comment: Because you did nothing with the response..... have a look at the documentation for [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: You are right! Fixed it, still doesn't work lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1st :** Should be enclosed by quotes `$('#button')`

**2nd :** Get the response in success function like this.

```
success: function(res) {

            $('#div').html(res);

          }
```

**3rd :** Set data type to text .

```
 dataType:'text'
```

**Update 1:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#button').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'test2.php',
            dataType:'text',
            success: function(res) { 

                $('#div').html(res);

            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Its because you haven't output the result you got from ajax.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'test2.php',
            success: function(data) { //<---result from ajax
                $('#div').html(data); //<----add result to div element
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your script is only a call of a page without GET/POST arguments, the **simpliest way with jQuery is $.load()** :

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#button').click(function() {
            $.load("test2.php #div");
        });
    });
</script>
```

doc here : http://api.jquery.com/load/